# Commandfield image not displaying

Tags: asp.net, gridview, commandfield

In my gridview I've got a commandfield with the Edit and Update. The text is displaying instead of the images. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvFleetSheet" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    AllowPaging="True"  PageSize="7" Width="1959px" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid"  
    CellPadding="3" BorderWidth="2px">
 <Columns>
 <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" InsertImageUrl="\\sos-sp\websites\SAB_Requests\Images\ico_edit.bmp" UpdateImageUrl="\\sos-sp\websites\SAB_Requests\Images\submit.png" /> 
  //other template fields....
 </Columns>
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC"  BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" 
             BorderWidth="2px" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: view source and look to see if there is an image tag there, maybe the image is failing to download... (returning 404)

Comment: It works fine on my side when I enter the image address, the icon displays (we have permissions on our server).....

Answer (score 0):

Image URL was wrong, should have been:

```
    InsertImageUrl="~/sos-sp/websites/SAB_Requests/Images/ico_edit.bmp"
```